# Error in line number = inputLine.nextInt();

Tags: java

I have an issue because it is saying that the int cannot be dereferenced!

```java
public class EducationalQuiz1{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int number;
        int inputLine;

        System.out.println("Select Topic:");
        System.out.println("1. Handball");
        System.out.println("2. Football");
        System.out.println("3. Basketball");
        System.out.println("4. Wrestling");
        String sport = Keyboard.readString();

        switch(sport){
            case "1":
                handball myhandball = new handball();
                myhandball.printMenu();break;
            case "2":
                football myfootball = new football();
                myfootball.printMenu();break;
            case "3":
                basketball mybasketball = new basketball();
                mybasketball.printMenu();break;
            case "4":
                wrestling mywrestling = new wrestling();
                mywrestling.printMenu();break;
            number = inputLine.nextInt();
            if (number < 0)
                System.out.println("Does not compute! Enter a positive number!");
            while (number < 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `inputLine` is never initialised.

Comment: You invoke `nextInt()` on `inputLine`, which is a primitive int type and as such does not have any methods. I assume you want to get the `nextInt()` from the user input instead.

Comment: `number = inputLine.nextInt();..` is inside the switch, probably not what you want. `while (number < 0);` is an infinite loop if number is negative.

Comment: `while (number < 0);` infintine loop

Answer (score 1):

What is dereferencing?

> Technically  any variable that is not a primitive type holds a
>   *reference* to an object, not the actual object itself. When you use the '.' operator to access a member of the object, you are
>   "dereferencing" the reference.

```
inputLine.nextInt();
```

`inputLine` is primitive type int you can't call methods with that, as it doesn't hold any reference so you get an error `int can't be derefrenced`

You should do something Like. Use `scanner` class to take the `int` input

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

> The nextInt(radix) method of java.util.Scanner class scans the next
>   token of the input as an Int

```
 scanner.nextInt();
```

Comment: In addition, even if it wasn't (seems like it should be a scanner), it's not initialised.

Comment: So can you tell me exactly what to do so I can arrange it?

Comment: Yes you are right,but I just pointed out the error ,`int cannot be dereferenced` @VLAZ

Comment: Maybe, you could do `String inputLine;` and `number = Keyboard.readInt();`

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question! How can you declare in a program that when a user enters a letter there is an error pls?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use scanner to input number like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
...

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = scan.nextInt();
```

Edit for your example:

```
...
switch(sport){
        case "1":
            handball myhandball = new handball();
            myhandball.printMenu();break;
        case "2":
            football myfootball = new football();
            myfootball.printMenu();break;
        case "3":
            basketball mybasketball = new basketball();
            mybasketball.printMenu();break;
        case "4":
            wrestling mywrestling = new wrestling();
            mywrestling.printMenu();break;
    }

  //put this out of switch statement
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  number = scan.nextInt();
        while (number < 0){
            System.out.println("Does not compute! Enter a positive number!");
            number = scan.nextInt();
        }
}
```

Comment: It is telling me unreachable statement

Comment: Where did you put it?

Comment: @Gianluca Aquilina I have edited it for your example! Just paste the code.

Comment: Do you have messenger?

Answer (score 1):

You invoke `nextInt()` on `inputLine`, which is a primitive int type and as such does not have any methods. I assume you want to get the `nextInt()` from the user input instead. Below some suggestions to optimize your code:

```
int number;
Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in); // Use a scanner instead of a primitive int

System.out.println("Select Topic:");
System.out.println("1. Handball");
System.out.println("2. Football");
System.out.println("3. Basketball");
System.out.println("4. Wrestling");
String sport = inputReader.next();

switch(sport){
  case "1":
    Handball myhandball = new Handball(); // Classes should be capitalized
    myhandball.printMenu();
    break;
  case "2":
    Football myfootball = new Football();
    myfootball.printMenu();
    break;
  case "3":
    Basketball mybasketball = new Basketball();
    mybasketball.printMenu();
    break;
  case "4":
    Wrestling mywrestling = new Wrestling();
    mywrestling.printMenu();
    break;
}

// Move this part outside the switch structure
number = inputReader.nextInt(); // Get the input from the user using a Scanner
while (number < 0) { // Prevent infinite loop by retrieving new input from user inside the loop
  System.out.println("Does not compute! Enter a positive number!");
  number = inputReader.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: thank you but it is saying that inputReader might not been initalized

Comment: Yeah, posted to fast, edited my response with the initialization a few minutes ago. But I'm sure this shows you the big picture and you can fill in the blanks yourself... :-)

Comment: What is your messenger name

Comment: Cause I need some help

Comment: Cause I just started